# How do you get code to execute at the end of a procedure?

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl, webspeed

I'm working on a new piece of code at work to assist the rest of the programmers in making app server calls.  Previously we just had a .i file and relied on the developer to make sure you made all the right calls and cleaned up the app server connection at the end of the program.  Obviously some people have forgotten to do that in the past and it's caused problems for us.

I've been building a basic appserver.cls file, but I can't figure out how to get it to disconnect at the end of the program.

---

I've tried the following things so far.

```
ON CLOSE OF THIS-PROCEDURE  
DO:    
    clAppServer:cleanupAppServer(). 
END.
```

This doesn't seem to fire at the end of the webspeed call.

```
DESTRUCTOR appserver():
    cleanupAppServer().
END DESTRUCTOR.
```

This works when it does garbage collection, but Progress doesn't seem to do garbage collection at the end of a webspeed call and the objects are still in memory (which is an entirely different issue that I need to deal with).

```
ON CLOSE OF SESSION:LAST-PROCEDURE  
DO:    
    clAppServer:cleanupAppServer(). 
END.
```

This doesn't even compile obviously.

I've tried a whole bunch of other things that are variants on these three to no avail.

---

Is there any way to do what I'm asking?  Bonus points if it can be inside the appserver.cls file.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand the question, you want to disconnect from another AppServer once the work is done. Would try something along the lines of the below work?

- Create a AppServer-handle-wrapper class. This class is responsible for the A/S connection; it has a public "Handle" (or similarly-named) property that you can use to run stuff on the AppServer.
- In this class' destructor you can add code that does your clean-up : disconnect and delete server handle .
- Code that wants to run something on the AppServer does something like ...

  def var asConn as AppServerConnection.

  asConn = new AppServerConnection().

  run foo.p on asConn:Handle (param1, out param2).

  // cause GC 
  asConn = ?.

  // manually destroy
  delete object asConn.

The destructor will then do the right thing.

Note that if you have this code in an internal procedure or method, then the variable would go out of scope at the end of it, and the GC would kick in.

There's an example of this approach at https://github.com/consultingwerk/ADE-Sourcecode/blob/566ac0a6e085d6305a8f364f13a1d805d3597d2a/src/netlib/OpenEdge/Net/ServerConnection/ClientSocket.cls

Bear in mind that in the ClientSocket is that the handle is private - you may want to make it public for a general AppServer connection.